# A poetic word or expression for networking/lobbying/making professional connections

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language, register, poetic

I’m looking for a poetic word or expression that means making professional connections, lobbying, networking, socializing professionally.

*League, circuit, club, society*, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Those are words for groups, not for an activity.

Comment: What do you mean by 'poetic'? In English, it is more than two hundred years since the notion of a distinct 'poetic diction' was challenged, and a hundred since the distinction died.

Answer (score 3):

Is it [*schmooze*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schmooze) you’re looking for?

Comment: *Behind the closed doors all the high-rollers schmooze / Jovial thanks to cigars and the booze* There, I just made it "poetic," even.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first say that limericks are also a form of poetry. In that spirit my answer is *hobnob*.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with [*rubbing elbows*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rub%20elbows) — or [*hobnobbing*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/hobnob).

Hunt and peck around those thesaurus links to look for others that may be more appropriate for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that comes to mind is **mingle**.

I've been hearing more frequently the word **politic** used as a verb.

"Let's meet tomorrow and *politic*."

Comment: If you include links to the meaning/definition of these words, you might get more upvotes.